# foreach loop saying that there are extra characters after close-brace. Cannot identify where

Tags: tcl

```
proc p_derived_bars args {
    *createmarkpanel elems 1 "select 3d elems"
    set buff1 ""
    set buff2 ""
    set i 0; set j 0
    foreach NodeList [hm_getvalue elems mark=1 dataname = nodes] cx [hm_getvalue elems mark=1 dataname=centrex] cy [hm_getvalue elems mark=1 dataname=centrey] cz[hm_getvalue elems mark=1 dataname=centrez] {
      append buff1 "GRID,[incr i],,$cx,$cy,$cz\n"
       foreach NodeId $NodeList {
         append buff2 "PLOTEL,[incr j],$i,$NodeId\n"
        }
    }

    set fpt [open temp.fem w]
    puts $fpt $buff1
    puts $fpt $buff2
    close $fpt
}
```

I cannot see where the extra space is, would someone mind helping me out. This is for Hypermesh.

Answer (score 4):

Here, you are missing a space:

```
  cz[hm
```

that will cause the incorrect number of arguments to be passed to foreach.